# PFFile location on disk

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've read in multiple places on the parse forums and stackoverflow that `PFFile` contents are saved to disk after they are downloaded. Where are they saved? How can I access the raw contents?

For context, I'm using `AVFoundation` and it doesn't play with `NSData` or `NSInputStream`. Right now I'm fetching the file from parse and writing the contents of `NSData` to the temp directory.

Comment: PFFile has property url. Take a look at the class reference: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html

Comment: It does, but I'm fairly sure that's the URL of where the file is stored in Parse's servers.

Answer (score 1):

Untested attempt at getting the cache location for a PFFile:

```
NSString *home = NSHomeDirectory();
NSString *library = [home stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library"];
NSString *docs = [library stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Private Documents"];
NSString *parse = [docs stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Parse"];
NSString *staging = [parse stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PFFileStaging"];
NSString *file = [staging stringByAppendingPathComponent:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p_%@", pffileobj, pffileobj.name]];
```

Comment: I figured out a way to do it - `[pffileobj performSelector:@selector(cachePath)];`

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the bytes and then write them to a directory that you know about. Then use that new file.